# Deserializing Java objects from Kafka consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kryo

I have a Kafka Consumer, currently configured with:

```
kafkaProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
kafkaProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
```

But what I really want is to be able to use a Kryo Deserializer instead:

```
public class KryoPOJODeserializer<T> implements Deserializer<T> {

    private Kryo kryo = new Kryo();

    @Override
    public void configure(Map props, boolean isKey) {
        kryo.setInstantiatorStrategy(new DefaultInstantiatorStrategy(new StdInstantiatorStrategy()));
        kryo.register( Arrays.asList( "" ).getClass(), new ArraysAsListSerializer() );
    }

    @Override
    public T deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
        // Deserialize the serialized object.
        return kryo.readObject(new Input(data), T.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }

}
```

What I can't figure out is, is it possible to reuse the same Consumer for different topics (each topic has a different type of POJO on it)? If my consumer config is:

```
kafkaProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KryoPOJODeserializer.class.getName());
```

Or, do I have to have a separate Consumer for every topic?

Alternatively, do I have to remove the generics part of my Deserializer, always return an Object, and cast the Object into the relevant POJO in the client code? Something like:

```
public class KryoPOJODeserializer implements Deserializer {

    private Kryo kryo = new Kryo();

    @Override
    public void configure(Map props, boolean isKey) {
        kryo.setInstantiatorStrategy(new DefaultInstantiatorStrategy(new StdInstantiatorStrategy()));
        kryo.register( Arrays.asList( "" ).getClass(), new ArraysAsListSerializer() );
    }

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
        // Deserialize the serialized object.
        return kryo.readClassAndObject(new Input(new ByteArrayInputStream(data)));
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }

}
```

The latter would work but it feels a bit dirty.

Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use you original approach by passing `Deserializer` instances directly into the Consumer:

```
KafkaConsumer<String, Foo> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties,
    new StringDeserializer(), new KryoPOJODeserializer(Foo.class));
```

If you want to reuse the same incoming data type for a number of topics then you can set up a subscription to those topics using a single consumer. If you want different object types for the values, then you will need to use multiple consumers.

Otherwise your second approach is also valid.

Comment: So I'm guessing it's acceptable to have (worst case) as many 'KafkaConsumer' consumers as I have Kafka topics? I sort of had it in my head that a KafkaConsumer was fairly heavyweight, something akin to a Hibernate SessionFactory. If that's not the case that makes life much easier!

Comment: Yes, that's acceptable - consumers (regardless of the messaging tech) are usually written to handle one particular payload type, though there are always exceptions. As to whether a KafkaConsumer is "heavy" that depends on what you mean. A consumer will maintain TCP connections to all brokers that it is consuming messages from. Other than that, there are no pools of threads doing things in the background.